# Connection Closed while trying to download string from URL

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient, connectionexception

I want to translate a string from one language to another. I tried this code:

```
        input = clipoard_word;
        string languagePair = "en|bn";
        string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        try
        {
             result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
        result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
        result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result.Trim());
        label1.Text = result;
```

But I am getting an exception on the line:

```
    result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

The error message says:

> the underlying connection was closed; an unexpected error was occurred
>   on a receive

What's wrong here and how can I solve this? N:B: I don't want to use google translator api here.

Comment: Could be a timeout issue. Try using [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202.aspx) instead?

Comment: hi is that work for you ???

Answer (score 0):

Hi Finally I found solution for you

you need to add this in your config file

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy />
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

**problem** --- **was that the  server simply took IE's proxy settings to perform the DownloadString call. My local IIS (7.0) requires that the proxy stuff must be configured correctly to enable server side http access to work properly. This can be done either by some setting in the web.config:**